# Linux Mint won't boot to GUI automatically

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, xorg, lightdm

Okay, I am out of ideas. There was a power failure during an upgrade, and now the system boots to the terminal, `tty1`, and the GUI does not load automatically. I have `lightdm` as my login manager. I can login and use `startx` to make Cinnamon load, but networking is still shot. I can not get `lightdm` to run for my life. I have tried dpkg-reconfigure on `lightdm`, `xserver-xorg`, and a bunch of other packages. Reinstalling Cinnamon doesn't help. And no, I do not have a NVidia card, so it's not a driver issue. I've also tried setting `HEED_DEFAULT_DISPLAY_MANAGER` to `false`.

System:

- HP Pavilion g4 Laptop
- amd64 Linux Mint 18
- Dual-core AMD Turion II
- ATI Radeon Graphics Card
- Dual-boot with Chromixium 16.04 i386

Answer (score 1):

Have you an older Kernel on your System? Boot it if posible. Try `sudo apt -f install` If this works without errors.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Comment: No. It is Mint 18 Sarah with fairly up to date packages.

Comment: Can you boot in recovery-mode? Have you Network then? Do you have closed-source driver installt? like nvidia?  If yes  investigate with `dkms status` the drivers are installt in the new Kernel.  'dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|^rc'
'

Comment: Yeah, recovery can boot. I can get network if I install `lxdm`, set it as my login manager using `dpkg-reconfigure`, and do `resume normal boot` and plug into ethernet. However, the bigger problem is I can't seem to get `mdm`, `lightdm`, or `gdm` to work. I can only get `lxdm` to work. `startx` does work though. **Edit:** I can use `nmcli d connect wlo2` to connect to WiFi, but it just enables a hotspot. Deleting the hotspot now makes the command seg fault.

Comment: Please post `nmcli d` and `nmcli c`  `dpkg -l | egrep  -v '^rc|^ii'` show Packages that are not fully instalt.Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and show `ls -al /usr/share/xsessions/`  Sorry I overread that you have no nvidia card.  I'm fighting here with english and the syntax

Comment: Life just got wierder. Wifi works fine with my USB wifi adapter, but not with the built-in one. Anyway, here's what you asked for: [StackExchange1 - Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zFexYi2k). I poke around some more.

Comment: Disconnect the usb-wlan-stick and remove it. `nmcli con up uuid b251a6f9-1f77-4c20-b112-6e47438f25d6` post error-messages. And `lspci -nnk | grep -i net A2`  and `dpkg -l | egrep 'linux-generic|linux-headers|linux-image` and `uname -r`